# Struggling to use stopwatch within keyboard hook

Tags: c#, winforms, macros, interop, keyboard-hook

i spend all day here but barely ever ask any question; you guys are so good i don't feel worthy (:

I have this application I made a while back which I started working on again recently.
It records a mouse click macro and replays it, it worked very fine for the use I would make of it but I started to feel the need to add keyboard strokes too.

So today I added this function that records keyboard strokes, I can catch the strokes and show them but my issue is with the fact that I want to run a stopwatch that starts on key press and ends on key release.
Besides I should make sure the key I press and the key I release are the same ones I hope this actually does it.

I tried a lot of different ways to run a stopwatch in there but everything about this piece of code makes me uncomfortable. The listener for the key should have separation for the keyup and keydown but how can i use the timer with this?

*By all means please go all out.*

---

Problem is, I tried instanciating the Stopwatch globally (Form1 scope) which should :

1. run the method 1 time, go to the keydown condition, start the timer,
2. then run another time, go to keyup and stop the timer.

I thought this should work but I guess I have scope issues considering the timer never gives an accurate value. (Pressing 3 seconds gives 1, afterwards pressing and releasing very quick gives 3) I checked to see if the timer starts and stop at the right time and I think it does.

Afterwards i tried instanciating it within the hook method but since it has to run twice for it to record up & down well the timer gets reset. (writing it like this i figure maybe i should just check if it's running and not instanciate it if it is)

I am not in a hurry and really not looking for just a quick way to solve this problem, rather looking for the best way to implement this feature and trying to make this program a bit tidier. I have a feeling this is way off and I should be  using lParam which would make it way easier.

---

I store keypress info in there, though I think lParam actually does this more efficiently, couldn't understand how it works though

```
public class KeyPressHelper
{
    public Keys currentPressedKeyCode;
    public Keys currentReleasedKeyCode;
    public Keys previousPressedKeyCode;

    public KeyPressHelper()
    {
        currentPressedKeyCode = new Keys();
        currentReleasedKeyCode = new Keys();
        previousPressedKeyCode = new Keys();
    }
}
```

this is the hook function, most of it is just the sample code provided by msdn, i added the condition for keyup, but im really not sure this is the actual right way to go.

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            keyStrokeTimer.Start();   // global Stopwatch

            //keypresshelper kph1
            kph1.previousPressedKeyCode = 0;
            kph1.currentReleasedKeyCode = 0;
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);   

            kph1.currentPressedKeyCode = (Keys)vkCode;
            kphList.Add(kph1);
        }
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
        {
            //assign kph2.previousPressedkey to kph1.currentPressedKey
            kph2.previousPressedKeyCode
 = kphList.Find(k => k.Equals(kph1)).currentPressedKeyCode;

            kph2.currentPressedKeyCode = 0;
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            kph2.currentReleasedKeyCode = (Keys)vkCode;

            //if they're identical well this is nice.
            if (kph2.previousPressedKeyCode == kph2.currentReleasedKeyCode)
            {
                keyStrokeTimer.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("" + keyStrokeTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds)        //goal.
            }
            else
            {
                keyStrokeTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    }
```

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: I edited the question sorry if it was vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let take a look at `Stopwatch` class [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

> By default, the elapsed time value of a Stopwatch instance equals the total of all measured time intervals. Each call to Start begins counting at the cumulative elapsed time; each call to Stop ends the current interval measurement and freezes the cumulative elapsed time value. Use the Reset method to clear the cumulative elapsed time in an existing Stopwatch instance.

As you see, the way you use it, your `Stopwatch` is accumulating the total time. If you want to measure the time between the two events, use [Restart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `Start`.

Comment: Thank you I will try it a bit later and post back how it goes. (failed git commit while leaving work :l )